# Got an IdeaPad S206, but only round Thinkpad chargers. How to charge?

Tags: laptop, power, thinkpad, adapter, charger

I'm working on a used Lenovo IdeaPad S206, to possibly make it donation-worthy. Right now, my problem is: Can't charge it! It uses a charger that's different than ThinkPad chargers (both the round and the rectangular socket variants).

Now, sure, I could buy a brand new IdeaPad S206 charger, but I want to avoid doing that. Is there some other, cheaper/easier way I could charge it? I was thinking of may adapting a charger I already have, but am up for any solution.

The laptop says it takes 20V, 2A as input.

[image]

Comment: You're asking 2 questions and for both the answer is "it depends". Perhaps better to buy a much cheaper 3rd party compatible charger.

Comment: @ChanganAuto: Let me rephrase the question then, so that "3rd-party charger" might also be an answer. I don't even know what this jack type is called...

Comment: Perhaps by a proper but inexpensive charger on eBay?

Comment: @John: The shipping costs to where I live are higher than a new charger...

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer:

It seems the input jack of your thicker, round, yellow Thinkpad charger is 7.9mm * 5.5mm (not sure what exactly each number measures); while the IdeaPad S206 is 5.5mm * 2.1mm.

Here is what an *opposite* adapter to the one you need looks like:

[image]

if you could only get this same adapter but with the maleness switched on both ends, that should do the trick: You would connect the Thinkpad charger to the female end, and stick the male end into the IdeaPad. The wrong direction [is pretty cheap](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32977438773.html), costing a little over 1 USD + a little for shipping. But can you find the right direction?